# `set-car!` of `cdr` changes `car` as well, why?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, scheme, mutability

```
(define l '(a))
(define p (cons l l))
(set-car! (cdr p) 'b)
```

After the last `(set-car! (cdr p) 'b)`, `p` will be `((b) b)` rather than `((a) b)`. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `cons` cell essentially contains two *pointers* to two other objects. Your code in question would translate roughly to this pseudo-C:

```c
struct cons {
    void *car;
    void *cdr;
};

cons *l = &cons{"a", NULL};
cons *p = &cons{l, l};  // no copy takes place, we're handling pointers here
p->cdr->car = "b";  // this changes the "l" object, and nothing else
```